# What is ConstraintLayout Optimizer?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Google published **ConstraintLayout 1.1.0 beta 6** on March 22, 2018. It has a new constraint known as ***Optimizer***. The documentation of Optimizer at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#Optimizer does not mention when to use and why to use it. Can someone shed some light about its usage.

Comment: It's more like priority, you can choose which element to prioritize, ex: direct constraints over barrier constraints

Comment: Can you elaborate it with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Constraint Layout 1.1 adds several new optimizations that speed up your layouts. The optimizations run as a separate pass, and attempt to reduce the number of constraints needed to layout your views.

In general they work by finding constants in your layout and simplifying them.

There’s a new tag, called layout_optimizationLevel, which configures the optimization level. It can be set to the following:

- **barriers** figures out where barriers are and replaces them with simpler constraints
- **direct** optimizes elements directly connected to fixed element, for example the side of the screen or guidelines, and continues to optimize any elements directly connected to them
- **standard** is the default optimization level which includes **barriers** and **direct**
- **dimensions** is currently experimental and can cause issues on some layouts — it optimizes the layout pass by calculating dimensions
- **chains** is currently experimental and figures out how to lay out chains of elements with fixed sizes.

If you want to try out the experimental optimizations dimensions and chains you can enable them on a ConstraintLayout with

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    app:layout_optimizationLevel="standard|dimensions|chains"
```

> Note: To clear whole concept, you must have to implement this.

Comment: Thank you! But when/where i should use it?

Comment: @AlexS You can check this [Constraint Layout 1.1](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/introducing-constraint-layout-1-1-d07fc02406bc)

Comment: How's your answer different from the documentation?