# ConstraintLayout Optimize detail

Tags: android, optimization, android-constraintlayout

Is the `ConstraintLayout`'s `layout_optimizationLevel` valid for subviews?

eg: `app:layout_optimizationLevel="standard"` is effect for `TextView`?

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_optimizationLevel="standard">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This might [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52197052/9763253)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`layout_optimizationLevel` is for parameters of `ConstraintLayout` that are used for laying out Views within it. Not for the View itself.

You can read some more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#Optimizer).

Comment: tks, i didn't notice that.

Comment: @ImagineOwl feel free to accept the answer if it helped you